# mask account number with string.format

Tags: string, formatting, masking

I have a bank account number that is variable length.

```
1234567890123
0987654321
```

I want to mask the account number for viewing, except for the last 4 digits.

```
XXXXXXXXX0123
XXXXXX4321
```

Is there a way to make it mask all the numbers but the last 4 using `String.Format` without using `Substring` to pull out the last 4?

**EDIT:**

There's nothing wrong with substring.  I'm just looking to see if there is a simple formatting string to convert all but the last 4 characters into something else.

Comment: What's wrong with using substring?

Comment: Seems like there's context missing - why are the restrictions that this needs to use String.Format and not use Substring?

Comment: Nothing.  I just want to know if it's possible. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with using substring?

However, if you put the number in a `long` (needed to hold all the digits), you could do `number % 10000` to extract the last four digits, and a fixed string for the XXX...

Answering the literal wording of the question, rather than what you probably really meant :) you could implement a custom formatter to printed masked account numbers, and then there would be a 'simple format string' that printed things in the way you want

The second example on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) formats (all the digits of) an account number. It could be modified to print a masked version instead.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with substring.  I'm just wondering if there's a format available that can convert all characters but the last 4 into an 'X'.  And the account number is a `String`

Comment: I realise the account number is a String. But convert it to a Long and mod 10000 will get the last four digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AccountNumberMasking {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String accountNumber = "1234567890123456";

        String maskedAccountNumber = maskAccountNumber(accountNumber);
        System.out.println("Masked Account Number: " + maskedAccountNumber);
    }

    public static String maskAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        int length = accountNumber.length();
        int visibleDigits = 4; // Number of digits to keep visible

        if (length <= visibleDigits) {
            return accountNumber; // no masking
        }

        StringBuilder masked = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < length - visibleDigits; i++) {
            masked.append('X');
        }

        masked.append(accountNumber.substring(length - visibleDigits)); //masked

        return masked.toString();
    }
}
```